# ceiling joist allowable span southern california

Tags: ceiling, framing, joists, span-tables

I'm adding ceiling joists in my garage. It's a 19' span between walls, and I'm using structural or #1 lumber. Should I use 2x8x22 OR 2X10X22 spaced 12" on center? I'll be adding 1/2" or 5/8" drywall.

Comment: You're asking two distinct questions here. Please revise to ask just one, and post a second question if you like. [Take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more.

Comment: Below the top of wall, which would give me 8' - 8'3"   ceiling from floor.

Answer (score 1):

You added below the top of the wall in the comments.  So I would lag a rim joist to the studs and use joist hangers.

Span will look like this:

2x10 @ 12oc for #2

2x8 @ 12oc or 2x10 @ 16oc for #1

2x8 @ 16oc for select

[span table](http://www.southernpine.com/app/uploads/SPtable16_060113.pdf)
[image: span table]